# Observe changes to a Map using a Proxy

Tags: javascript, proxy, ecmascript-6

I use a Map javascript object. I'd like to observe changes to a Map instance using a Proxy object. However, whatever handler object I try to feed in to the proxy, I consistently get the error `Method Map.prototype.set called on incompatible receiver`. What am I doing wrong? The idiomatic example I expect to work looks like

```
var map = new Map();
var proxy = new Proxy(map, {
    set(obj, prop, value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
proxy.set(1, 1); --> error
```

I also tried setting a handler for `apply`, but to no avail.

Comment: Nothing you're doing in your snippet will actually trigger a `set` trap in the first place. Your code also reproduces if you do `new Proxy(new Map, {}).set(1, 1)`

Comment: You are neither assigning properties to the proxy nor are you calling it as a function, that's why neither the `set` nor `apply` traps work

Comment: @Bergi Ugh I searched and could not find a good duplicate, alas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, understand that your error also reproduces with just

```
var map = new Map();
var proxy = new Proxy(map, {});
proxy.set(1, 1);
```

It is not related to your usage of `set(obj, prop, value)`.

#### Why it fails

To break that a bit more, understand that this is basically the same as doing

```
var map = new Map();
var proxy = new Proxy(map, {});
Map.prototype.set.call(proxy, 1, 1);
```

which also errors. You are calling the `set` function for `Map` instances, but passing it a `Proxy` instead of a `Map` instance.

And that is the core of the issue here. `Map`s store their data using an private internal slot that is specifically associated with the `map` object itself. Proxies do not behave 100% transparently. They allow you to intercept a certain set of operations on an object, and perform logic when they happen, which usually means proxying that logic through to some other object, in your case from `proxy` to `map`.

Unfortunately for your case, proxying access to the Map instance's private internal slot is not one of the behaviors that can be intercepted. You could kind of imagine it like

```
var PRIVATE = new WeakMap();
var obj = {};

PRIVATE.set(obj, "private stuff");

var proxy = new Proxy(obj, {});

PRIVATE.get(proxy) === undefined // true
PRIVATE.get(obj) === "private stuff" // true
```

so because the object pass as `this` to `Map.prototype.set` is not a real Map, it can't find the data it needs and will throw an exception.

#### Solution

The solution here means you actually need to make the correct `this` get passed to `Map.prototype.set`.

In the case of a proxy, the easiest approach would be to actually intercept the access to `.set`, e.g

```
var map = new Map();

var proxy = new Proxy(map, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    // Perform the normal non-proxied behavior.
    var value = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);

    // If something is accessing the property `proxy.set`, override it
    // to automatically do `proxy.set.bind(map)` so that when the
    // function is called `this` will be `map` instead of `proxy`.
    if (prop === "set" && typeof value === "function") value = value.bind(target);

    return value;
  }
});

proxy.set(1, 1);
```

Of course that doesn't address your question about intercepting the actual calls to `.set`, so for that you can expand on this to do

```
var map = new Map();

var proxy = new Proxy(map, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    var value = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    if (prop === "set" && typeof value === "function") {
      // When `proxy.set` is accessed, return your own
      // fake implementation that logs the arguments, then
      // calls the original .set() behavior.
      const origSet = value;
      value = function(key, value) {
        console.log(key, value);

        return origSet.apply(map, arguments);
      };
    }
    return value;
  }
});

proxy.set(1, 1);
```

Comment: The proxy will not hold the methods of ```Map``` like ```entries()```?

Comment: @MaorBane That should work fine.